# In TensorFlow 2.0: Training error with optimizer.apply_gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to learn the new TF 2.0 alpha release. I'm training a `Sequential` model for a binary classification purpose. My datatable is `df`, which is a numpy array. `classification` is the one-hot encoding dataframe of the classes I must predict.

The definition of the model is clear, as it is the definition of loss and accuracy functions and the (Adam) optimizer. 
However, I get an error at the point of training:

```
loss_history = []
accuracy_history = []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        # compute binary crossentropy loss (bce_loss)
        current_loss = bce_loss(model(df), classification.astype(np.float64))
        loss_history.append(current_loss)

        # train the model based on the gradient of loss function
        gradients = tape.gradient(current_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients([gradients, model.trainable_variables])  # optimizer = Adam


    # print the training progress
    print(str(epoch+1) + '. Train Loss: ' + str(metrics) + ', Accuracy: ' + str(current_accuracy))

print('\nTraining complete.')
```

At this point, I get error pointed at `optimizer.apply_gradients()`. The error message says:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Where is my mistake?

I did some research on this type of error, but I found nothing useful related to this particular function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By accepting the answer the question is already marked as solved. No need to edit the question. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```